# How to Save not Save As

Tags: c#, save, savefiledialog

I'm creating a richtextbox editor and need to put a save function as well as a save as. I can easily do a save as function by using the savefiledialog but im not sure how to save without this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a field somewhere, say `string filename`. Set it to `null` initially.

When a document is opened, store the file name in a `filename`.

When a document is saved through Save As, also store this file name in `filename`.

When Save is invoked, check the value of `filename`. If it is `null`, invoke Save As instead. If it is not `null`, save to the file name specified in `filename`.

Comment: And if you have a Load() to fill the editor from a file, then also set that 'filename'.

Comment: thank you exactly what I needed. Just another question though. How would I make a message box show if you went to click "New document" button and the text had been changed since it was last saved. I know how to do the message box etc. but not for only when the document has been edited and not saved..if you understand..:-S

Comment: @Pops: When the file is changed then set an `UnsavedChanges` bool to true.  When it is saved set it to false.

Answer (score 5):

The way this usually works is to keep track of the file name the user either opened or saved as.

Then, when they use the Save function, simply save to the file name that was previously specified. If no file has been specified, then show the Save As.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't "Save" simply the following (in pseudocode)?

```
Save() = 
    WriteTo(oldfilename)

SaveAs() = 
    stream = OpenDialog()
    oldfilename = stream.filename
    Save()
```